# How to stop auto increment and instead resume

Tags: php

please i have a problem with mysql database..each time i register a user on my website, it inserts it into the DB and works fine..here's the problem, when i delete a particular column and try inserting a new column, instead of it to start from the previous number, it just keeps incrementing..In short, if i have a table with 5 columns, and i delete column 5,anytime i insert a new record into the database, instead of it to start from 5, it starts from 6 and so on.hope you get my question.what can be done to stop this unnecessary increment?..and i have this php code..it does not login into my db and retrieve my data..what could be wrong as well??

Comment: Regarding "i have this php code..it does not login into my db and retrieve my data..what could be wrong as well??": Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InnoDB as your MySQL storage engine, then it is not possible to do what you ask. If you choose to use a different storage engine, you could accomplish what you want with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = number
```

That said, this is likely not a good idea. MySQL's auto-incrementing system should be left alone and not used for counting.

Instead, add a new field to your table called rowcount and run the following command after each insert:

```
UPDATE table SET (rowcount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to change auto-increment in database. If you want to show row numbers serially in a page, just use loop and show all row number serially like this

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
echo $i;
echo $row['yourvalue'];
$i++;
}
?>
```